# Dishwasher drainage problem

Tags: plumbing, drain, drainage, dishwasher, motor

I recently got a "new" (used) dishwasher and have installed it myself. It is a *Frigidaire Ultra Quiet iii*. There is a problem with it draining water. Here is what the setup looks like:

[image]

The pink is the drainage hose. **Note that the hole in the side of the wall is near the ground while the pipe is about 2ft off the ground.**

The water does not drain (at least not fully). There is always a little puddle in the bottom of the diswasher. I've researched a bit and found some discussion about a high loop. So I tried that. I used the clips on the side of the dishwasher to make a loop:

[image]

This still does not properly work. I checked the end of the drainage pipes and there doesn't seem to be anything blocking in there (I put a screw driver in and it's clear, plus the sink drains just fine).

So to diagnose, I disconnected the pipe end of the hose and put it into a bucket just to see if it drains, like so:

[image]

**THIS WORKS!**

It drains very well into a bucket. The pump is clearly doing it's job.

So my suspicion is that the 2nd loop is a bit tough for the pump to push through. Could that be correct? The fix would be to drill a hole near the top of the wall such that there is no loop down before it goes into the drainage pipes. Before I drill, I just want to confirm that this could be the issue.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try keeping the drain hose low to the ground until it gets to the hole in the cabinet, then up through the hole and continue up to a high loop and down to the connection on the tail piece. One up, one down, not a roller coaster. I Think i saw that dishwasher on a children's animated TV show. ;) "Hi boys and girls, I'm Dishy the Dishwasher".

Comment: @AlaskaMan No bueno. I even tried drilling a new hole now and going straight on the floor, up to the top of the cabinet wall, then down into the drain. Doesn't work.

Comment: Go high as soon as possible and then slope downwards will be best, but long drain hoses don't work well. Fitting an AAV at the high point of the hose may help.

Comment: If the pump isn't able to drain any water and there are no blockages in the drain hose and obstructions in the pump case than the pump is bad. Some pumps are accessible and can be opened and replaced. If not might have to bite the bullet.....

Comment: Also did you put a high loop in the drain hose when you tested it with the bucket?

Answer (score 1):

The drain loop is taking the place of a vacuum breaker you'd see on the counter. The loop really has no bearing on how the machine drains. It only stops (hopefully) water from flowing back to the DW from the drain. The pump is obviously working correctly as you mentioned when you checked with a bucket. What you didn't mention or check was whether  the DW was empty of water. In fact unless the water level inside is sloshing around, some residual water will most likely remain simply because the impellers cant force small amounts of liquid out the hose. Some will remain in the sump at the case bottom and then pumped out on the next drain cycle. Your first and only loop should be above the drain where the hose enters the sink drain. Make the top of the loop touch the counter top underside. Unless your DW pump is faulty or damaged it will expel water easily through the loop and down the drain.